# Scrapy and XPath selecting generically

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I've just started with `Scrapy`, went through some examples and wrote a `spider` on my own, but now I have a problem generically selecting text data.For example how would I select only a text from a table cell if it isn't always in unique format:

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <td>
        <div id="somediv1">
              <span>blablabla</span>
         </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="somediv2">
              <span>text2</span>
         </div>
          <div id="somediv3">
              <span>text3</span>
         </div>

         <span>text4</span>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

So, text inside cells will be nested inside unknown tags and I would like just to extract clean text without any tags of course.

Comment: Something like an XPath of "//text()" maybe?

Comment: Well, text() returns empty list, that's probably because everything is inside div or span

Comment: Even `//text()` returns an empty list?

Comment: Yeah, //text() returns empty list  for <td> element that contains divs and spans

Comment: Strange - given the sample above - I get 18 matches - then being a bit more refined and using `tree.xpath('//text()[normalize-space()]')`, I get `['blablabla', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4']`

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
//table//td//text()[normalize-space()]
```

This selects any non-all-whitespace text node that is a descendent of a `td` that is a descendent of a `table` element of the XML document.

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:for-each select="//table//td//text()[normalize-space()]">
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
=============   
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="somediv1">
                <span>blablabla</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="somediv2">
                <span>text2</span>
            </div>
            <div id="somediv3">
                <span>text3</span>
            </div>
            <span>text4</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and all selected text nodes are copied to the output, using a visually distinctive delimiter string**:

```
blablabla
=============   
     text2
=============   
     text3
=============   
     text4
=============
```

**Update**:

In case the source XML document is in a default namespace, the above XPath expression should be changed to account for this fact:

```
//x:table//x:td//text()[normalize-space()
```

where the prefix `"x"` is bound to the default namespace of the source XML document.

**Here is a complete example**, XSLT - based:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:for-each select="//x:table//x:td//text()[normalize-space()]">
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
=============   
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided one, but put in a default (the XHTML) namespace:

```
<table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="somediv1">
                <span>blablabla</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="somediv2">
                <span>text2</span>
            </div>
            <div id="somediv3">
                <span>text3</span>
            </div>
            <span>text4</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**again the same correct result is produced**:

```
blablabla
=============   
     text2
=============   
     text3
=============   
     text4
=============
```